# Change registry value permission command line or NSIS

Tags: windows, cmd, permissions, registry, nsis

I'm trying to grant ordinary users write access to a registry value I created.

They cannot have write access to the parent key.

Through `regedit`, it's simple:
 1. Select value
 2. Edit Permissions (change accordingly)
 3. OK

However I'm struggling to do the same via command line or NSIS.

- The command [`regini`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237607) has a very nice method for changing `key` permissions.  If this worked for changing `value` permissions, I could easily script it into my installer.
- The NSIS plugin [`AccessControl`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) has a very nice method for changing `key` permissions but no evidence of changing `value` permissions.

In this case, the `key` is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` which I will not modify the permissions of.

How can I change **only** the permissions of the value I've created?  How can I do this just as `regedit` allows, but silently through command line or NSIS?

The value would be something like:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"My Value"="C:\Please\Let\Me\Change\Permissions\Sadface.exe"
```

Note, this is for scripted software installer which build script will run on Mac, Linux and Windows (NSIS allows this).  Recommendations for bundling special `dlls` or Windows executable is OK so as long as they're easily bundled and chained against at install time.  Solutions including tools such as Windows SDKs cannot be accepted unless the footprint is small and so as long as the DLLs can easily be bundled and included into a LGPL 2.1 project.  e.g. installing users will have to run this, so solutions need to be reasonably portable/distributable.

Comment: If you look at the title bar of the permissions dialog you will see you are changing permissions on the run key not the value. Values don't have security. Use the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  Will have to investigate more creative approaches to solve this particular problem, thank you.

Comment: Use the all users startup folder. As it's a file you can set permissions with `icacls`. Use `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to find it.

Comment: @Noodles Kudos and thanks for reading between the lines.  Will use that approach for the underlying objective (to make system wide autostart of an application controllable by all users).

Comment: @Noodles Interesting catch-22 problem with the `icacls` solution... Granting permission to delete is a success, but once the file is deleted, creating a new one becomes impossible due to the parent's  permissions.  I suspect the only way to circumvent this problem is to leave behind a dummy shortcut (to the equivalent of `/bin/true` on Linux).  Thoughts welcome.

Comment: I think I'll swap it to this on disable: http://superuser.com/a/389288/443147

Comment: Write a batch file that always runs. The batch just runs a batch file if it exists elsewhere, a folder just for all your users.

Comment: @Noodles batch files show pop-ups so that's undesired.  The `rundll32.exe` trick works well.  The library I'm using for writing the shortcut maintains permissions, so I'm writing a disabled shortcut with a red-x through it (shell32.dll #131) pointing to `rundll32.exe` when disabled, regular icon pointing to my real EXE when enabled.  Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: Great. Have to type more ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Noodles mentions in the comment above, it's not possible to change `value` permissions, so no solution exists.  Registry editor is actually providing the `key` permissions, which is observable by looking at the Window title, and which is undesired for this particular solution.